# Backbone - advice in simple application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hello this is my simple application in backbone:

> https://jsfiddle.net/quygo8vh/

Sorry that all JS code is in one file but jsfiddle has no other option. I'm not skilled in backbone as I would like to and I have a simple how-to questions.

Can someone look at my code and advice me what I'm doing wrong, how it should be done in a right way.

My main problem was in edit action. Basically I just did this:

```
editView = new EditView();
editView.setModel(App.users.get(id));
editView.render();
```

but then I have problem with multiple instance of `EditView` and on the second update I've got duplicate update of model :).

Answer (score 0):

That is because on creating a new instance of EditView, you are also adding the event listener again, to the same element :

```
'click #update-user': 'updateUser'
```

This listener will keep on adding on every instance creation.

What you can do is, instead of creating a new edit view, you can trigger an event on the model, like :

```
model.trigger('editUserDetails')
```

Catch this event in your AddView and just update your view,something like this:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'editUserDetails', this.updateView);
```